# Probability Distribution of z/x given x

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, machine-learning

It may seem a simple question for you, but it's driving me crazy. Given the regression model $z = wx + \epsilon$, where $ \epsilon \sim \mathcal{N} (0, (\sigma x)^{2}  $, $ z \sim \mathcal{N}(wx, \sigma^2 x^2)  $, and the value of $\sigma$ assumed to be known.

What is the distribution of $z/x$ given $x$ ?

Maybe I'm missing something. I opted for a change of variable, such that $y = z/x$ and I tried to model the probability of $p(y|x)$, but I just got lost in my computations.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want $\frac {z} {x} | x$, you can consider $x$ as known, as a constant. Then, for the properties of the normal distribution, $ \frac {z} {x} | x \sim N(\frac{wx}{x}, \frac{\sigma^2 x^2}{x^2})=N(w,\sigma^2)$.

Please, check my reasoning, but I think that it is like this.

Comment: it makes sense, actually. I'm just wondering why I didnt come up with the same answer yesterday :( 
May I accept the answer later (few hours)? I would like to check it deeper.

Comment: Sure! Take your time :)